# GAE dev server behind Apache proxy sometimes slow

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

As the Google App Engine development server only serves one file at a time, I decided to have static resources served instead by: *Apache 2.2.17 / XAMPP 1.7.4 / WinXP32*. Requests for dynamically created resources are routed to the GAE development server, using Apache's "ProxyPass". Works reliably and fast in general.

However, when accessed via Apache, a dynamically created resource sometimes takes a very long time to load. At first I thought that this is due to the GAE development server responding slowly. But when loading the same resource directly from the GAE development server, then the response is *always* fast.

What may be the reason for these slow responses?

Excerpt from the Apache log (note the wait from 10:10:42 to 10:10:53):

```
[Fri Aug 05 10:10:42 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to localhost
[Fri Aug 05 10:10:42 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2576): proxy: HTTP: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost)
[Fri Aug 05 10:10:53 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1735): proxy: start body send
[Fri Aug 05 10:10:53 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1839): proxy: end body send
```

Apache configuration, shortened:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081
Listen 127.0.0.1:8081
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
    ProxyPass /demo/images !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    Alias /demo/images "C:/Scratch/realitybuilder/demo/images"
    <Directory "C:/Scratch/realitybuilder">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem using Apache as a reverse proxy for GAE development. I ended up solving it by switching to [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main). It's faster, and also easier to configure. You can see an example config [here](http://desmondbrand.com/blog/2011/12/05/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-speedy-app-engine-development/).

Comment: Just put that in the TODO list for the project in question, thanks! (unfortunately I cannot vote up your answer due to my lack of reputation)

Comment: No problem, once you verify nginx works you could come back and mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Finally got back to GAE development, and verified that nginx indeed does the trick (on WinXP)!